# URL encode space to '%20' instead of '+'

Tags: http, url, xss

Is there a way to prevent the browser from url-encoding a space to "+" and encode to "%20" instead? Just by modifying the input.

e.g. something like `<iframe{some_special_character}src="http://www.example.com/index.php">` where some_special_character when url encoded will give '%20' instead of '+'.

some_special_character is the answer I'm interested in.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that

```
<iframe
src="http://www.example.com/index.php">
```

will skip the space entirely,
so my problem disappeared all of a sudden.